# Adding custom buttons to WMD Editor

Tags: javascript, textarea, wysiwyg, markdown, wmd

Is there a way to add custom buttons to the [**WMD Editor**](http://wmd-editor.com/) that extends the editor's functionality?

My ideas for various buttons I want to add are to:

- Markup the selected text
- Insert some predefined text

Thanks
Turgs

Comment: Is there a standing way to extend WMD Editor... or any of the variations such as Stack Overflow's version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

1) you need extend the Images "wmd-buttons.jpg"

edit the image and add a button for extended functionality.
2) Add Script for the button to bind with an event(like inserting some text)

```
        var Insertbutton= document.createElement("li");
        Insertbutton.className = "wmd-button";
        Insertbutton.id = "wmd-insertsometext-button";
        Insertbutton.title = "Emphasis <em> Ctrl+v";
        Insertbutton.XShift = "-60px";
        Insertbutton.textOp = command.inserttext;
        setupButton(inserttextButton, true);
        buttonRow.appendChild(inserttextButton);
```

3) Now Define inserttext function and place your insertion code.